# How to cause pytest to print a one line traceback and captured output?

Tags: python, pytest, command-line-arguments

When a test fails, I need pytest to print both a single line traceback and the output to stdout and stderr from the failed test. After reading the [pytest command line reference](https://doc.pytest.org/en/latest/reference/reference.html#command-line-flags), it seems that the --tb=line and --show-capture=all options should do that. At the bottom of my test.py file, I added this call to pytest.main:

```
pytest.main(["-v", "--tb=line", "--show-capture=all", __file__])
```

Unfortunately, the --tb=line option overrides the --show-capture option, and pytest doesn't show the captured stdout and stderr. This seems strange to me because the captured output is not part of the traceback, so I don't understand why the --tb option has any effect on the --show-capture option.

Is there any set of options that causes pytest to print both a single line traceback and the captured output?

Comment: Just been banging my head against the wall with this. Surely this is possible? I don't spend a lot of time in python for the reason that the 'standard' libs are such a challenge -  how did it get decided that these two args are incompatible?